# Update a dictionary with values from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a Dictionary here:

```
dic = {'A':1, 'B':6, 'C':42, 'D':1, 'E':12}
```

and a list here:

```
lis = ['C', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'F']
```

What I'm trying to do is (also a requirement of the homework) to check whether the values in the lis matches the key in dic, if so then it increment by 1 (for example there's 3 'C's in the lis then in the output of dic 'C' should be 45). If not, then we create a new item in the dic and set the value to 1.

So the example output should be look like this:

```
dic = {'A':1, 'B':6, 'C':45, 'D':2, 'E':12, 'F':1}
```

Here's what my code is:

```
def addToInventory(dic, lis):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        for i in lis:
            if i == k:
                dic[k] += 1
            else:
                dic[i] = 1
        return dic
```

and execute by this code:

```
dic = addToInventory(dic,lis)
```

It compiles without error but the output is strange, it added the missing F into the dic but didn't update the values correctly.

```
dic = {'A':1, 'B':6, 'C':1, 'D':1, 'E':12, 'F':1}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to iterate over a dictionary when it supports random lookup. You can use `if x in dict` to do this. Furthermore, you'd need your `return` statement outside the loop.

Try, instead:

```
def addToInventory(dic, lis):
    for i in lis:
        if i in dic:
            dic[i] += 1
        else:
            dic[i] = 1
    return dic

out = addToInventory(dic, lis)
print(out)
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 45, 'D': 2, 'E': 12, 'F': 1}
```

As [Harvey suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020065/how-to-update-the-values-from-list-into-a-existing-dictionary-in-a-loop-python/46020103#comment78999943_46020103), you can shorten the function a little by making use of `dict.get`.

```
def addToInventory(dic, lis):
    for i in lis:
        dic[i] = dic.get(i, 0) + 1 

    return dic
```

The `dic.get` function takes two parameters - the key, and a default value to be passed if the value associated with that key does not already exist.

---

If your professor allows the use of libraries, you can use the `collections.Counter` data structure, it's meant precisely for keeping counts.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(dic)
for i in lis:
     c[i] += 1

print(dict(c))
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 45, 'D': 2, 'E': 12, 'F': 1}
```

Comment: Is `if i in dic:` better than `if dic.get(i):`?

Comment: @ScottBoston By fractions. Because `dic.get(i)` results in a function call followed by an evaluation of the return value. `if i in dic` _should_ be faster.

Comment: One line: `dic[i] = dic.get(i, 0) + 1`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my bad, the return statement was outside the loop, typo

Comment: @Harvey Good suggestion! If the Counter is not a valid option, this is a nice alt.

Comment: `if dic.get(i):` will also screw you up if any of your keys are falsey.  For instance, if `dic[i]` is 0, this test will act the same as if `i` were not in `dic`.  If you want to use a fancy dict method, you can do something like `dic[i] = dic.get(i, 0) + 1`

Comment: @TravisSu That's not the only problem though.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sort of understand this, I get used to write C/C++ and thinks about iterating it all the time